# wrap_content create problems

Tags: android, image, android-layout

Having a strange issue, Image given below having size of 136x166

[image]

when I set this in ImageView/Button with `wrap_content` then this image became large

```
<Button
  android:id="@+id/btn_reports"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@drawable/report_image" />
```

Output: with wrap_content

[image]

```
<Button
      android:id="@+id/btn_reports"
      android:layout_width="136px"
      android:layout_height="166px"
      android:background="@drawable/report_image" />
```

Output: with fixed sized imagesize(original 136x166)

[image]

Why so, anybody faced this issue?

Comment: Which drawable folder have you put the image into? Maybe its scaled up because its in the wrong density folder?

Comment: where have you placed this image exactly?

Comment: having only one folder "drawable" with no suffix.

Comment: @PareshMayani wherever I take result is same.

Comment: Please test and check the result on real device.

Comment: @PareshMayani already done same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because I created icon for `hdpi` and putting icon in `drawable` folder rather than `drawable-hdpi`

I got the solution by my own while doing research [Application support multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242111/application-skeleton-to-support-multiple-screen) screen and you can find the answer [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12258061/739270)